# scroll both parent LinearLayout and Listview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview, scrollview

I have the following layout

```
<LinearLayout
 android:orientation="vertical"
 ...
/>

  <include .../>
  <include .../>

  <ListView ... />
</LinearLayout>
```

Naturally the content of the ListView scrolls. But what I want is for the entire LinearLayout to scroll concurrently with the ListView, appropriately of course: i.e. both should scroll until only the ListView is on screen. I already tried wrapping the LinearLayout with a ScrollView. That's not working

Comment: listview scrolls naturally as content grows using it inside scrollview is not a good practice

Comment: @IllegalArgument my objective is to make the `include`s scroll as well. How might I do that without including them in the ListView's adapter?

Comment: the best way would be to set a custom header to your listview doing this would relieve you of your scrollview and your header will scroll as well but its just an idea have not implemented it myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inflate a custom view using layout inflater then use this:

```
myList.addFooterView(myFooter);//for header
myList.addHeaderView(myHeader);//for footer
```

Comment: I thought of that. The problem is I need my ListView to have marginLeft and -Right that the `header` isn't supposed to have. The reality is that I need the adapter to have that left-right margin. But for some reason I can't seem to add the margin. The row is a RelativeLayout with a background. So padding doesn't work. Even if I wrap the RelativeLayout inside a FrameLayout and add the margin to the FrameLayout, the RelativeLayout still fills the width of the row. Basically the question would now change to: How do I pass margin to a ListView while the header does not share in that margin. +1

Comment: I fixed it. With the FrameLayout, I needed to add the margins to the RelativeLayout